# Difference between ON CONFLICT vs ON CONSTRAINT primary key

Tags: postgresql

Will there be any performance difference interms of locks/speed etc in that case?

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
 employee_id int PRIMARY KEY,
 full_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 manager_id INT
);
```

By `on conflict`:

```
insert into employees (employee_id, full_name)
values (6, 'Yuvraj Singh')
ON CONFLICT (employee_id)
do
update set full_name = EXCLUDED.full_name;
```

by `on constraint`:

```
insert into employees (employee_id, full_name)
values (6, 'Yuvraj Singh')
ON CONSTRAINT employees_pkey
do
update set full_name = EXCLUDED.full_name;
```

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking this yourself? If so, post the results. If not, do some homework.

Comment: Those queries do exactly the same thing (assuming the schema fits). Why would you expect any difference?

Comment: What difference in performance did you see when you tested this? (And why do you care because no company has billions of employees anyway)

Comment: The second one is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance, there should be no significant difference between the two methods. Both methods are just different ways of specifying the unique constraint that would trigger the conflict action.

Because of the `UPDATE` method that is called to resolve the conflict the actual performance would depend more on factors like the size of the table, the distribution of data, the load on the database, etc.

In terms of locks, it'll be the same because any conflict will result in locking the row.